# How to get images from a camera connected using I2C to Pi 4B?

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, gpio

I have a [OV2640 binocular board](https://robu.in/product/ov2640-binocular-camera-module-cmos-stm32-driver-3-3v-16001200-for-3d-measurement-with-sccb-interface/) that I want to connect to raspberry pi 4B. However I have previously not worked with such embedded system so I require some additional help.

For now my aim is to simply get an image from both of the cameras. Till now, I have connected the 3.3V, GND, SCL and SDA cables. I can successfully detect the board using `sudo i2cdetect -y 1`. However I do not have any Idea how to proceed further. The module has many other pins like DCLK, PWDN, VSYNC, HREF, D0 - D7, RST, NC. I have no idea if I need to connect all these and where to connect them. The documentation and files attached on the website do not seem to be of much help. There it would be great to get some reading material on how to get started and how to proceed with this module.

I am using raspberry pi 4B with manjaro arm aarch64

I have tried reading the documentation on the webiste (under attachments) but as I said it is of no use, I believe they used it as a part of a larger project and just dumped the file in the archive. This further becomes problematic due to my lack of knowledge in this field.

I have tried compiling Arducam for the OV2640 camera and PI, but currently it gives me error with undefined smbus functions. I believe this is due to a particular smbus and i2c-dev dependency which I cannot find on pacman or AUR. I am however unwilling to further waste any more time debugging as I am not sure that is the correct path forward. I need some guidance with that.